# （時間）後の正確な言い方について

Tags: grammar, expressions

最近気まぐれ気ついたのは、時間を表す語と漢字「後」と組み合わせるときのルールがまだわからないのでした。例えば、英語の`One year later`は日本語で「一年間後」じゃなくて、「一年後」であります。逆に、`One week later`はなぜか「一週後」じゃなくて、「一週間後」になります。日本人の友達に問いかけても、「ただ習慣だからね」って答えましてんです。ですから、ここで問題を提出したいと思いました。

（時間）後と言う時、どんな場合で「間」の字が要りますか。〇〇間の後と言う表現もありそうですね。

- 「三日後{みっかご}」か「三日間後{みっかかんご}」か「三日間の後{あと}」
- 「一週後」か「一週間後」か「一週間の後」
- 「一年後」か「一年間後」か「一年間の後」
- 「一日後」か「一日の後」

どう言うルールがあるんですか。ところで、〇〇間後の場合は「あと」と読むことなく、いつも「ご」と読むのですか。

Comment: 「一週後」を言わない理由は、「いっしゅう」だと「一周」と「一週」の読み方が同じなので、区別がつきやすいように「一週間」というのだと思います。なのでOne Weekだけ特別に「一週間」のように「間」を付けているのかなと思います。

Comment: 「三日後」と「三日間の後」の違いは、「三日後」は三日経ったちょうどのことを指していて、「三日間の後は」三日経った以降のことを指しているように思います。「三日後に会いましょう」はちょうど三日後に会うという意味で、「三日間の後に会いましょう」だと三日を過ぎれば四日目でもいいし五日目でもいい、という感じになります。三日間は会えないというニュアンスになります。

Comment: 「[一日後]{いちにちご}」とはあまり言いませんね。読みの問題というより「明日」とか「次の日」のような別の言い方をするからかもしれませんが。

Comment: たしかに「一日後」はあまり言わないですね。今から一日後の場合は「明日」と言いますね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「三日後」→OK、「一年後」→OK、「一日後」→OK、週だけは話すときに「週」と「周」の区別がつきづらいので「一週間後」→OK、となるのだと思います。「三日後」は三日経ったちょうどあたりを指して、「三日間の後」は三日を過ぎた以降の期間を指します。「の」に続くときは「あと」と読むのはそれが単独の語として使われるときは訓読みの「あと」と読むのが一般的だからです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。では「一年間後」と「三日間後」の表現もいけますか。

Comment: 「一年間後」と「三日間後」は使わないです。「一年後」「三日後」と同じ意味になるからだと思います。

Answer (score 1):

そもそも期間を表す表現として「一週」よりも「一週間」の方がよく使われます。この二つに特に意味の違いはありません。一方、「三日間」や「一年間」の場合、「間」があることによって「三日」や「一年」よりも「〜を通して」（英語で言うと throughout）の意味が強調されます。「〜後」と言う場合に「間」を言わないのはそのためかもしれません。

Comment: はっきりとわかりました。ご解答ありがとうございます。